# condition hyperlink not passing vendor_rating_id

Tags: php, url, hyperlink, conditional-statements

I have a view called `vendors with ratings`. It has a column called `rate vendor`. This column contains a conditional hyperlink that says “rate vendor” for all vendors that have not been rated by the current user and it says “edit rating” for all vendors that have been rated by the current user. Each user is only allowed to rated each vendor one time but this conditional hyperlink allows the user to edit that rating via the `vendor_ratings_edit` page. The “rate vendor” link works and opens up the `vendor_ratings_add` page and defaults to the correct vendor. However, the “edit rating” links do open up the `vendor_ratings_edit` page but it does not default to the correct vendor rating in which I am trying to update. The syntaxt I am trying to use is below:

```
$rs = DB::Query("select * from `vendor_ratings` 
WHERE 
(`vendor_id`='" . $data["vendor_id"] . "')
And
(`added_by`='".$_SESSION["user"]."')
");
If ($rs->fetchAssoc() )
$value = "<a href='vendor_ratings_edit.php?editid1=" . $data["vendor_rating_id"] . "'>Edit rating</a>";
else
$value = "<a href='vendor_ratings_add.php?vendor_id=" . $data["vendor_id"] . "'>Rate this vendor</a>";
```

For some reason the url is not showing the `vendor_rating_id`. It looks like this:

http://localhost:8085/vendor_ratings_edit.php?editid1=

Any suggestions on why the url is not showing the `vendor_rating_id`? The `Vendors and Ratings` view does not contain the `vendor_rating_id` column, obviously. It is in the `vendor_ratings` table. Is this the reason? If so, what syntax should I use to get the "edit rating" link to pass the information needed for the `vendor_ratings_edit` page to default to the correct vendor rating?

Comment: you need to fix the formatting so we can understand this.

Comment: `$data` is not defined anywhere, is it suppose to be the result from your query?

Comment: Yes. It's supposed to be the result of my query but I'm not sure what you mean by defining $data. Also, how do you format questions without all the spaces disappearing? How do you get the query in that grey sliding box?